# Eclipse ADT is not Samsung s3 as android device ??

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-mobile

Well, my samsung s3 is not detected as android device but as portable media player gt-19300

http://cubixshade.com/images/s3.png

I set "Always prompt to pick up device" on Eclipse Run Configuration and when I run the application, no device is shown or detected.

How will my phone will be detected as active android device in eclipse ?

Comment: did you check your device manager?is your device shows in yellow(Unknown mark)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this issue for my `Samsung Galaxy y S5360` by  installing Samsung Kies from [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/). And you would be able to sync your Samsung mobile with your PC and it includes almost every device driver for almost every Samsung device in the market. And then your device should be recognized by Eclipse. It is a worth a try.

Answer (score 6):

Install Samsung Kies or install your device drivers manually:

```
Device Manaager -> yourDevice -> UpdateDriverSoftware -> Browse My Computer ... -> Let Me Pick From a List -> Samsung Android ADB InterFace
```

Comment: Neither of those works.  The Android Device Chooser shows my Galaxy S3 as an unknown target.

Comment: @DeanSchulze : you downvote because of this answer doesn't solve your issue? it may help somebody else as upvotes shows.